# Symfony 3.4 : Repository method not found

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entity

i want to add a method in my repository class ;
this is my repository class 'PanierRepository' :
( path : src/techeventBundle/Repository/PanierRepository.php )

```
namespace techeventBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PanierRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findAllOrderedByName($iduser){}
}
```

and this is my entity class called 'Panier' :
(Path:src/techeventBundle/Entity/Panier.php)

```
namespace techeventBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Panier
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="panier", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="userid", columns={"userid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="techeventBundle\Repository\PanierRepository")
 */
class Panier
{
```

and this is where i want to call this repository method , in a controller of another bundle and i have already included the entity (use techeventBundle\Entity\Panier;) : 
(Path : src/reservationBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php)

```
 $panier = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('techeventBundle:Panier')->findAllOrderedByName($iduser);
```

the repository method when i call it  is not found ! 
Notice : i haven't generated the entities after adding the repository
please help and thanks !

Comment: Check first that you don't get a null object when using `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('techeventBundle:Panier');`

Comment: $panier = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('techeventBundle:Panier')->find(1);
is not displaying any error

Comment: It does not display an error for find because your are getting the default entity repository.  Your entity is not properly mapped to the repository.  Possibly because you have older generated mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine which interfere with the annotations.

Comment: @Cerad what's the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepostory( ...
```

[image]

finally, ... your code should be:

```
$panier = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('techeventBundle:Panier')
    ->findAllOrderedByName($iduser);
```

or

```
$panier = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository(techeventBundle\Entity\Panier::class)
    ->findAllOrderedByName($iduser);
```

Comment: The fairly new ... syntax in php is kinda cool but I don't think that is the problem here.  And you are mssing the closing ) and semicolon.

Comment: Please read the updated response with a screenshot from official documentation

Comment: Glad you got it working but I just wanted to point out that there is no difference between $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository and $this->getDoctrine()-getManager()>getRepository.  At some point you fixed your repository mapping problem without realizing it.